# Maven: SunCertPathException when accessing self-signed repository

Tags: java, maven, ssl, ssl-certificate, keytool

I set up repository for maven artefacts that allows only https/ssl access. When running a maven build I naturally get this exception:

```
        sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: 
    PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: 
unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

In an attempt to fix this I downloaded the certificate of my repository and imported it into my local keystore as trusted location. The certificate seems to be installed correctly, when I print the keystone's content.

I rebooted my computer in the mean time, too. There should be anything that is in cache from before. 
When running the maven build again I still get this above security exception. Does anyone have an idea what the issue could be?

Comment: did you check if you have the certificate installed under the %JAVA_HOME%\lib\security\cacerts of the JVM that maven uses?

Comment: I will post it as an answer then. feel free to accept :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make sure that the certificate is installed under the `%JAVA_HOME%\lib\security\cacerts` of the JVM that maven uses. If it is not there you need to import it.

Command for checking whether the certificate is installed:

```
keytool -list -keystore "%JAVA_HOME%/jre/lib/security/cacerts
```

command to import

```
keytool -import -noprompt -trustcacerts -alias <AliasName> -file   <certificate> -keystore <KeystoreFile> -storepass <Password>
```